# Reading first 10 folders in directory / R Programming Language

Tags: r, directory

I have been working on a dataset of folders and subfolders (folder -> subfolder - > file)
I have trouble reading the first 10 folders of data. I have used the below code but it doesn't work. Please help

```
> for(i in seq_along(my_folders)){
+ my_data[[[i]]] = list.files(path = "~/dataset1", recursive = TRUE)
```

Below see problem with reading txt file in subfolder:

```
> for(i in 1:13){
+ current_dir = dirs[i]
+ lines = readLines(mydata[[i]])}
```

This gives error: Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument

But outside of the loop this works:

```
> lines <- readLines(my_data[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sequoia's answer works, but in R you can take advantage of concise [functional programming](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions), which @langtang's answer gets at with `lapply()`. Try this one-liner:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

d <- dir_ls("path/to/folders", recurse = TRUE) %>% walk(~read_lines(.x))
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of that:

```
dirs = list.dirs(recursive = FALSE) # reads all directories/folders
mydata = list() # create empty list
for (i in 1:10) { # only takes the first 10 directories
  current_dir = dirs[i]
  mydata[[i]] = list.files(path = file.path("~/dataset1", current_dir), recursive = TRUE)
}
```

You only have to adapt your folder structure

Comment: What about reading the txt file in the subfolder? I can read it outside the for loop with lines <- readLines(my_data[[1]]) but in for loop                                                                   
  > for(i in 1:13){
+ current_dir = dirs[i]
+ lines = readLines(mydata[[i]])} it  gives me following error: Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument

Answer (score 1):

Use `dir` to get a vector of file names, for example all .txt files in folder "f" and all it subfolders

```
files= dir("f",pattern = ".txt", full.names = T,recursive = T)
files
[1] "f/f1/f1_1/f1_1.txt"
[2] "f/f1/f1_2/f1_2.txt"
[3] "f/f2/f2_1/f2_1.txt"
[4] "f/f2/f2_2/f2_2.txt"
```

Then read them using `readLines`

```
lapply(files, readLines)
```